Cannot assemble my code: waring: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text', warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
I tried to replicate the assembly workspace that i have to study on my windows pc (where i have instruction to how installe and use wsl) on my linux pc but when i try to assemble by using
./assemble.ps1 ./file.s

i get this 2 warnings:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco4Rb1Y.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld:, warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE

The code that i'm trying to assemble is a simply testing code:
.include "./files/utility.s"

.data
msg: .ascii "Ok /r"

.text
_main: nop
    lea msg, %ebx
    call outline
    ret


The utility file is a file useful for our students goals, nothing i think is influences the problem.
I read something about addressing with rip referencing (or eip in my case where i have 32bit) but didn't work
The assemble.ps1 file is
param (
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$sourcePath,
    [switch][Alias('f')]$force = $false
)

$isPathValid = Test-Path -PathType Leaf $sourcePath
if(-not $isPathValid) {
    Write-Host 'Path invalid';
    exit
}

$fileHeader = file $sourcePath;
$isExecutable = $fileHeader -like "*ELF 32-bit*";
if($isExecutable) {
    if(-not $force) {
        Write-Host 'The file is an executable';
        exit
    }
    else {
        Write-Host 'The file is an executable';
    }
}

$sourceFile = Get-ChildItem $sourcePath;

$dir = $sourceFile.Directory;
$name = $sourceFile.BaseName;

gcc -m32 -o "$dir/$name" '-Wa,-a' '-Wa,--defsym,LINUX=1' > "$dir/$name.lst" -g ./files/main.c $sourceFile
if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    Write-Host "Assembler error"
}

the utility.s file is:
#.nolist

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.ifdef DOS

.TEXT

inchar: 
        PUSH %EBX
inchar_loop:
        MOV  %AX,%BX 
        MOV  $0x07,%AH 
        INT  $0x21
        MOV  %BH,%AH
        
        CMP  $0x0A, %AL         # ignore LF, for input redirection with CRLF files.
        JE   inchar_loop        # redirection with LF files is not supported
        
        POP  %EBX
        RET

.endif

.ifdef LINUX

.DATA
ic_tmp: .byte 0                 

.TEXT
inchar:  PUSH %EBX
         PUSH %ECX
         PUSH %EDX
inchar_loop:
         PUSH %EAX
         MOV $3,%EAX            # sys_read
         MOV $0,%EBX            # fd of stdin
         LEA ic_tmp,%ECX        # address of buffer
         MOV $1,%EDX            # read 1 character
         INT $0x80
         POP %EAX
         MOV ic_tmp,%AL

         CMP $0x0D, %AL         # ignore CR, for input redirection with CRLF files
         JE inchar_loop         # redirection with LF files is supported

         CMP $0x0A, %AL         # convert LF to CR, to have the same ENTER behavior as DOS
         JNE inchar_next
         MOV $0x0D, %AL

inchar_next:
         CMP $0x7F, %AL         # convert delete (0x7f) to backspace (0x08)
         JNE inchar_fine        # because Linus decided that the backspace key should send a delete command...
         MOV $0x08, %AL

inchar_fine:
         POP %EDX
         POP %ECX
         POP %EBX
         RET

.endif

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.ifdef DOS

.TEXT
outchar: PUSH %EAX
         PUSH %EDX
         MOV $0x02,%AH
         MOV %AL,%DL
         INT $0x21
         POP %EDX
         POP %EAX
         RET
         
.endif

.ifdef LINUX

.DATA
oc_tmp: .ASCII  "0"

.TEXT
outchar: PUSH %EAX
         PUSH %EBX
         PUSH %ECX
         PUSH %EDX

         MOV %al,oc_tmp
         MOV $4,%EAX       # sys_write
         MOV $1,%EBX       # fd of stdout
         LEA oc_tmp,%ECX   # address of buffer
         MOV $1,%EDX       # write 1 character
         INT $0x80

         POP %EDX
         POP %ECX
         POP %EBX
         POP %EAX
         RET

.endif

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TEXT
inbyte:  PUSH %EBX
         MOV  %AH,%BH
         CALL inhexchar
         CALL outchar
         MOV  %AL,%AH
         CALL inhexchar
         CALL outchar
         CALL HA2B8
         MOV  %BH,%AH
         POP  %EBX
         RET
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
inword:  CALL inbyte
         MOV  %AL,%AH
         CALL inbyte
         RET
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
inlong:
indword:  CALL inword
         SHL  $16,%EAX
         CALL inword
         RET
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
outbyte: PUSH %EAX
         CALL B8HA2
         XCHG %AL,%AH
         CALL outchar
         XCHG %AL,%AH
         CALL outchar
         POP  %EAX
         RET
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
outword: XCHG %AL,%AH
         CALL outbyte
         XCHG %AL,%AH
         CALL outbyte
         RET
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
outlong:
outdword: ROL  $16, %EAX
              CALL outword
              ROL  $16,%EAX
              CALL outword
              RET

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------//------------------------------------------------------------------------------#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
newline: PUSH  %EAX
         MOV   $0x0D,%AL
         CALL  outchar
         MOV   $0x0A,%AL
         CALL  outchar
         POP   %EAX
         RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.DATA
L247513: .ASCII  "Checkpoint number "
L247003: .ASCII  "x. Press any key to continue"
L247893: .FILL 1,4

.TEXT
pause :  NOP
pause0:  MOVB $0x30,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause1:  MOVB $0x31,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause2:  MOVB $0x32,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause3:  MOVB $0x33,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause4:  MOVB $0x34,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause5:  MOVB $0x35,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause6:  MOVB $0x36,L247003
         JMP L271893
pause7:  MOVB $0x37,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause8:  MOVB $0x38,L247003
         JMP L271893     
pause9:  MOVB $0x39,L247003
         JMP L271893     
L271893: PUSH %EAX
         PUSH %ECX  
         PUSH %ESI
         CALL newline
         MOV  $L247513,%ESI
         MOV  $(L247893-L247513),%CX
L247527: MOV  (%ESI),%AL
         CALL outchar
         INC  %ESI
         DEC  %CX
         JNZ  L247527
         CALL newline
         CALL inchar
         POP  %ESI
         POP  %ECX
         POP  %EAX
         RET

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
inline:  CMP     $2,%CX
         JB      L409ABB  # salta a fine
         CMP     $80,%CX
         JA      L409ABB  # salta a fine

         PUSH    %EAX
         PUSH    %EBX
         PUSH    %ECX
         PUSH    %EDX

         MOV     %CX, %DX   # salva numero caratteri iniziale
             
L4004C:  CMP     $2, %CX      #ciclo
         JE      L40093       #salta a quasi fine
         CALL    inchar    
         CMP     $0x0D,%AL
         JE      L40093      # salta a quasi fine 
            
         CMP     $0x08,%AL   
         JE      L67193      #salta a elimina carattere
             
L50193:  CALL    outchar
         MOV     %AL,(%EBX)
         INC     %EBX
         DEC     %CX
         JMP     L4004C      #torna in ciclo

#elimina carattere
L67193:  CMP     %CX, %DX    #impedisce di cancellare oltre l'inizio del buffer
         JE      L4004C      
         DEC     %EBX        
         INC     %CX
         MOV     $0x08, %AL
         CALL    outchar
         MOV     $0x20, %AL
         CALL    outchar 
         MOV     $0x08, %AL
         CALL    outchar
         JMP     L4004C
                 
L40093:  MOV     $0x0D,%AL   #quasi fine
         CALL    outchar
         MOV     %AL,(%EBX)
         INC     %EBX
         MOV     $0x0A,%AL
         CALL    outchar
         MOV     %AL,(%EBX)
         POP     %EDX
         POP     %ECX
         POP     %EBX
         POP     %EAX
L409ABB: RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TEXT
outline: PUSH %EAX
         PUSH %EBX
         PUSH %ECX
         MOV $80,%CX
L4001B:  MOV  (%EBX),%AL
         CMP  $0x0D,%AL
         JZ   L4002A
         DEC %CX
         JZ   L4002A
         CALL outchar
         INC  %EBX
         JMP  L4001B
L4002A:  CALL newline
         POP  %ECX
         POP  %EBX
         POP  %EAX
         RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TEXT
outmess:   PUSH   %EAX
       PUSH   %EBX
       PUSH   %ECX
L087509:   CMP    $0,%CX
       JE     L087508
       MOV    (%EBX),%AL
       CALL   outchar
       INC    %EBX
       DEC    %CX
       JMP    L087509
L087508:   POP    %ECX
       POP    %EBX
       POP    %EAX
       RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TEXT
inhexchar: CALL  inchar
            CMP   $'0',%AL
            JB    inhexchar
            CMP   $'F',%AL
            JA    inhexchar
            CMP   $'9',%AL
            JBE   L3A89B3
            CMP   $'A',%AL
            JB    inhexchar
L3A89B3:    RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
B4HA1:    AND    $0x0F,%AL
          CMP    $9,%AL
          JA     L3ACD37
L3ACD30:  ADD    $0x30,%AL
          RET
L3ACD37: ADD    $0x37,%AL
          RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
B8HA2: PUSH    %ECX
       MOV     %AL,%CH
       SHR     $4,%AL
       CALL    B4HA1
       MOV     %AL,%AH
       MOV     %CH,%AL
       CALL    B4HA1
       POP     %ECX
       RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HA1B4:    CMP     $'9',%AL
          JA      L3KCD37
sub_0x30: SUB     $0x30,%AL
          RET
L3KCD37:  SUB     $0x37,%AL
          RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.TEXT
HA2B8:   PUSH  %ECX
         MOV   %AL,%CH
         MOV   %AH,%AL
         CALL  HA1B4
         MOV   %AL,%AH
         ROL   $4,%AH 
         MOV   %CH,%AL
         CALL  HA1B4
         OR    %AH,%AL 
         POP   %ECX
         RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
outdecimal_byte:
outdecimal_tiny:  PUSH %EAX  
                  AND  $0x000000FF,%EAX 
                  CALL outdecimal_long 
                  POP  %EAX 
                  RET 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
outdecimal_word:
outdecimal_short:  PUSH %EAX  
                  AND  $0x0000FFFF,%EAX 
                  CALL outdecimal_long 
                  POP  %EAX 
                  RET 
#-----------------------------------------------------------
.DATA
resti_cifre:      .fill 11,1

.TEXT
outdecimal_long:  PUSH  %EAX
      PUSH  %EBX
                  PUSH  %ECX
                  PUSH  %EDX
                  PUSH  %ESI
                  PUSH  %EDI
    PUSH  %EBP

                  MOV   $10,%ECX
                  CMP   $999999999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $99999999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $9999999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $999999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $99999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $9999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $999,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $99,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $9,%EAX
                  JA    long_L4013K
                  DEC   %ECX

long_L4013K:      LEA   resti_cifre,%EDI
                  MOV   %ECX, %EBP
                  ADD   %ECX,%EDI      # EDI punta sotto alla cifra da inserire per prima
                  DEC   %EDI           # EDI torna a puntare alla prima cifra da inserire
ciclolongL4013K:  MOV   $0,%EDX        # costruzione del dividendo EDX:EAX
                  MOV   $10,%ESI       # divisore in ESI
                  DIVL  %ESI   
                  AND   $0x0000000F,%EDX # sistemazione del resto_cifra codificato ASCII
                  ADD   $0x30,%DL
                  MOV   %DL,(%EDI) 

                  DEC   %EDI   
                  DEC   %ECX
                  CMP   $0,%ECX        # Controllo fine ciclo
                  JNE   ciclolongL4013K

                  LEA   resti_cifre,%EBX
                  MOV   %EBP, %ECX
                  CALL  outmess  

                  POP   %EBP
                  POP   %EDI
                  POP   %ESI
                  POP   %EDX
                  POP   %ECX
                  POP   %EBX
                  POP   %EAX
                  RET
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.TEXT
indecimal_byte:
indecimal_tiny:   MOVB  $3,num_cifre_1eWK7
                  PUSH %EBX
                  PUSH %EAX
                  CALL converti_1eWK6
                  MOV  %AL,%BL
                  POP  %EAX
                  MOV  %BL,%AL
                  POP  %EBX
                  RET

indecimal_word:
indecimal_short:   MOVB  $5,num_cifre_1eWK7
                  PUSH %EBX
                  PUSH %EAX
                  CALL converti_1eWK6
                  MOV  %AX,%BX
                  POP  %EAX
                  MOV  %BX,%AX
                  POP  %EBX
                  RET

indecimal_long:   MOVB  $10,num_cifre_1eWK7
                  CALL  converti_1eWK6
                  RET

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Converta da decimale a binario in EAX

.DATA
prodotti_parziali_1eWK7:   .fill 1,4
num_cifre_1eWK7:            .fill 1,1

.TEXT   
converti_1eWK6:    NOP
        PUSH %EDX
P_di_0_1eWK7:    MOVL  $0, prodotti_parziali_1eWK7
                 
ciclo_1eWK7:  CMPB  $0x00,num_cifre_1eWK7     # termina se cifre finite
                      JE    fine_1eWK7
new_cifra_1eWK7:   CALL  inchar                    # prelievo eventuale nuova cifra
                      CMP   $0x0D,%AL                 # termina se ritorno carrello
                      JE    fine_1eWK7 
                   
                      CMP   $'0',%AL                  # scarta cifre non decimali
                      JB    new_cifra_1eWK7
                      CMP   $'9',%AL
                      JA    new_cifra_1eWK7
                      CALL  outchar

                      PUSH  %EAX                      # nuovo prodotto parziale
                      MOV   $10,%EAX
                      MULL  prodotti_parziali_1eWK7    
                      MOV   %EAX,prodotti_parziali_1eWK7
                      POP   %EAX          
                      AND   $0x0000000F,%EAX
                      ADDL  %EAX, prodotti_parziali_1eWK7

                      DECB  num_cifre_1eWK7                  
                      JNE   ciclo_1eWK7                        
                  
fine_1eWK7:           MOV   prodotti_parziali_1eWK7,%EAX 
                      POP %EDX
                      RET
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
.DATA
LZ647513: .BYTE   0x0A,0x0D,0x0A,0x0D
          .ASCII  "Press Q to exit . . . "
LZ567893: .BYTE

.TEXT
exit:          MOV  $LZ647513,%ESI
               MOV  $(LZ567893-LZ647513),%CX
LZ247AA7:      MOV  (%ESI),%AL
               CALL outchar
               INC  %ESI
               DEC  %CX
               JNZ  LZ247AA7
waitQ_LZc247A: CALL inchar
               CMP  $'Q',%AL
               JNE  waitQ_LZc247A

.ifdef DOS
               MOV $0x4C,%AH
               INT $0x21
.endif

.ifdef LINUX    
               MOV $0x0001,%AX
               INT $0x80
.endif

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

.global _main


You can get English error messages by setting the environment variable LC_ALL to C.  That said, it'll be hard to diagnose the problem without you showing us the code in question.

I update the question with the code, hope it helps

Simplest is to disable PIE. Otherwise yeah, you will need to use position independent addressing for which the usual trick is to call a helper function that fetches the return address and then you reference everything from there.

Is this 32 bit code?  It doesn't look clear.

how can i disable PIE?
(yes is a 32 bit code as i say in the question)

Use the appropriate flag to the linker, probably -no-pie. You did not show your assemble.ps1.

EIP-relative addressing modes don't exist in 32-bit mode; they're specific to 64-bit mode.  Windows WSL does not run 32-bit Linux programs, so are you sure that you're not working with 64-bit?

I add my assemble.ps1 code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Since 32 bit does not natively support EIP-relative addressing, you will have to do it by hand. The usual way is to write a function that grabs the return address from the stack which you can then use as a fixed reference point. Something like this:
_main: nop
    call geteip
eip:
    add $msg - eip, %ebx
    call outline
    ret

geteip:
    mov (%esp), %ebx
    ret

Of course if you don't require PIE you can disable that with a linker option (probably -no-pie) and then you can keep your relocations.

i tried your code but it gives me the same error, i also tried the linker option -no-pie but it says "assemble.ps1: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'no-pie'."

Do you still get the error if you remove the add $msg - eip, %ebx? Just to verify that is the line causing the problem.

yes i still get the same message

Then the problem is elsewhere in code not shown, probably in your utility.s.

i add the utility.s file

Yeah, for example LEA ic_tmp,%ECX already requires a relocation. If you do not want to rewrite the utility.s I would say check how you added the -no-pie to the build script, maybe you missed the - or something.

If you can tell me exactly how to write the full script with also -no-pie i will be very gratefuly

I would think you should just replace the gcc -m32 with gcc -m32 -no-pie

Sorry but i think i'm doing something wrong in the powershell terminal, in my windows pc i just type ./assemble.ps1 ./file.s and it works, there what i have to type in the pwsh terminal?

Edit the script and add the -no-pie to that line.

It says: assemble.ps1: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'no-pie'.

Did you edit the script and change that line?

Yes, this message apperaed after i wrote ./assemble.ps1 ./file.s -no-pie

You are not supposed to do that. Edit the script and change the gcc -m32 to gcc -m32 -no-pie.

Sorry i didn't understand that i have to modify the assemble.ps1 file, thank now it works correctly
